# Constraint Layout performing differently in different devices

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using Constraint Layout in my Android Studio project and found that while testing on different devices the elements in my layout appear at different positions . And sometimes some of them are not even appearing at all . Could anyone suggest a solution.

Comment: I suggest you to show code and devices that you test it...

Comment: share your layout code. maybe there is constraint issue